# Can a marriage be valid if the man is a revert whose parents are Muslim and Hindu?

Tags: nikah, conversion, parents

Can a marriage be called valid if a Muslim girl marries a man reverted to Islam and had Muslim mother and Hindu father

Comment: The fairh of the parents is irrelevant to any marriage.

Answer (score 2):

The faith of the relatives of the spouse isn't a condition for marriage.

Allah says in the [Quran (2:221)](https://quran.com/2/221):

> And do not marry polytheistic women until they believe. And a
>   believing slave woman is better than a polytheist, even though she
>   might please you. And do not marry polytheistic men [to your women]
>   until they believe. And a believing slave is better than a polytheist,
>   even though he might please you. Those invite [you] to the Fire, but
>   Allah invites to Paradise and to forgiveness, by His permission. And
>   He makes clear His verses to the people that perhaps they may
>   remember.

As seen  from the verse, it is the faith of the would be spouse and not that of his/her relatives that Islam is concerned about.

Also w.r.t Jews, Christians and other people of the book:

> This day [all] good foods have been made lawful, and the food of those
>   who were given the Scripture is lawful for you and your food is lawful
>   for them. And [lawful in marriage are] chaste women from among the
>   believers and chaste women from among those who were given the
>   Scripture before you, when you have given them their due compensation,
>   desiring chastity, not unlawful sexual intercourse or taking [secret]
>   lovers. And whoever denies the faith - his work has become worthless,
>   and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers. [Quran (5:5)](https://quran.com/5/5?translations=20)